# flutter run ProcessException: No such file or directory

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-run

I am getting following error while running my Flutter app on Android device. I am using latest Android Studio and Emulator as of today. App works fine on Web and iPad simulator.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
ProcessException: No such file or directory
  Command: /Users/malwinder/StudioProjects/demo-app-flutter-azure-function/Flutter App/android/gradlew -q -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64 -Ptarget=/Users/malwinder/StudioProjects/demo-app-flutter-azure-function/Flutter App/lib/main.dart -Pbase-application-name=android.app.Application -Pdart-defines=Q0xJRU5UX0FQUF9TV............

......4Y2FmYjlmOTVhLw== -Pdart-obfuscation=false -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=false -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
```

Also, app used to run well few days ago. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out project again and ran it and this issue no longer appeared